# findOneAndUpdate mongoose; Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

After a record is created, I'm trying to use $push to send the ID for the record that was just created into a different model.

```
likeRoutes.route('/add').post(function(req, res){
    let like = new Like({
        value: req.body.value,
        _report: req.body._report
    })
    like.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
            console.log('in router - card id', req.body._report)
            console.log('doc id', doc)
        Report.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body._report },
            { $push: { like: doc._id } },
            { new: true , useFindAndModify: false },
            (err, post) => {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                    res.json({doc})
            }
        )
    })
})
```

When I run this, I keep getting the error of `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

I previously had it configured like this:

```
Report.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body._report },
```

And it was adding the like record to the same report everytime, and did not look up by ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `res.send` and `res.json` one after the other.

Try this:

```
likeRoutes.route('/add').post(function(req, res){
    let like = new Like({
        value: req.body.value,
        _report: req.body._report
    })
    like.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) return res.send(err)

        console.log('in router - card id', req.body._report);
        console.log('doc id', doc);

        Report.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body._report },
            { $push: { like: doc._id } },
            { new: true , useFindAndModify: false },
            (err, post) => {
                if (err) return res.send(err);

                res.json({doc})
            }
        )
    })
})
```

Now in case of an error you are stop execution and return the error. If no error - you are sending the result.